# Unifying these files together

Tags: r, single-cell

I have two .csv files

One for raw read counts of each gene and the other 3114 single cells for four patients which should be the row names of the first file

As single cells per patients seems duplicated I am getting error and don't know how to read them together

Any way this is the files

https://www.dropbox.com/s/slkhspz7lgdgph6/ascites.csv?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iq8lt7qrh7hdtq8/ascitesRownames.csv?dl=0

I tried

```
a=read.csv("ascites.csv")
Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
b=read.csv("ascitesRownames.csv")
View(b)
View(a)
rownames(a)=b
```

> Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) :    duplicate 'row.names'
> are not allowed In addition: Warning message: non-unique value when
> setting 'row.names': ‘logical(0)’

Any help in having a matrix in row names are 3114 single cells and genes in columns?

Comment: Can you please ``dput()`` the head of files so we don't have to download them from dropbox? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems:

- As Ram RS said you get a data frame when you load that second CSV.  Since the information is stored in a row rather than a column you need a little more work to extract it too.
- R will silently mangle your column names from the first data frame and will also interpret the second file as having column names (and then mangle those too) unless you give extra arguments to `read.csv` to prevent it.
- The fact that you only have four identifiers (not 3114) in the second file means you can't use those as row names.  Your rows in `a` are cells, not patients, right?  You could make up something unique based on both patient and cell info but I'd suggest avoiding that.

First you could use something like this (going straight from Dropbox here) to read the files without losing information:

```
a <- read.csv("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/slkhspz7lgdgph6/ascites.csv", check.names = FALSE)
b <- read.csv("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/iq8lt7qrh7hdtq8/ascitesRownames.csv", header = FALSE)
```

Then, since you want to associate more information than can easily fit in a "wide-format" (matrix-like) data frame, and row and column names are so easily mangled by R, I'd suggest using a "long-format" data frame instead.  The package reshape2 is very helpful for this.  Here you can put the patient IDs as an additional column in your first data frame, explicitly label the cells, and then make a new data frame where each row is a cell and gene combination for a particular patient:

```
a <- cbind(patient = as.character(b[1, ]), cell_id = 1:nrow(a), a)
gene_counts <- reshape2::melt(
  a, id.vars = 1:2, variable.name = "gene", value.name = "count")
```

So you get something like this:

```
> head(gene_counts)
  patient cell_id gene count
1   7873M       1 A1BG     1
2   7873M       2 A1BG     0
3   7873M       3 A1BG     2
4   7873M       4 A1BG     0
5   7873M       5 A1BG     1
6   7873M       6 A1BG     0
```

(Note the gene column is a factor there.)

I'd be very careful with row and column names since R is so prone to altering them without warning, and in general with assuming things will match up in the right order like the rows of the one table and the columns of the other.  Hadley Wickham has a good summary of the problems with row names in particular:

https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#rownames

Comment: +1 agree with the comment about row names. I think data.table has the right idea in doing away with them completely and using keys instead.

Answer (score 0):

`read.csv` produces a data.frame. You'll need `rownames(a) <- b$col_name`, not `rownames(a) <- b`.